# Ubuntu 20.04 - Hp hplip: HP Device Manager can't find device, while the setup can

Tags: printing, hp

I have followed the directions found online for installing my HP printer.
Downloaded the install from the official website (version HPLIP-3.21.8), and run till conclusion.

Now I can open either Settings, or the HP Device Manager. If I open the HP Device Manager, it says that "No Installed HP Devices Found" and to either run the terminal command hp-setup, or to just open the Setup to add a new device.

So, if I open the Setup, I choose a USB Device Discovery method, and my printer is correctly found, I select it, and I click "next", and finally I click "add Printer", and no errors come out. So, I suppose my Device has been installed, but when I open again the HP Device Manager, it keeps saying "No Installed HP Devices Found".

To conclude, I cannot either print or scan from any software. How can I solve it?

Comment: Which exactly  HP device do you have? How HPLIP was installed?